# How to "capture" child_process output in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, youtube-dl

I'm using youtube-dl to download videos from YouTube. When I call it from node.js spawn child_process, it downloads video, everything works fine, but I'm not able to get any information from child_process to my program. 
I would like to get progress information, how much of file is downloaded, or error description if there is any, and so... 
Also, I would like to capture data into readable stream in main process instead of saving it directly to file.

Is there any recommendation that you have on how to achieve this?

Comment: This looks like a programming question -- it might be more appropriate on Stack Overflow. (They'll want you to include the code you're currently using in your question, though.)

Comment: Yes it's about peogramming. I think that code isn't important here because I need to find out what tool should I use to achieve this. Thanks for response